# JavaScript querySelectorAll classname innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I have following element :

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.apply-dealer-xyz').innerHTML = "Deselect";
```

```html
<button class="btn cta-primary apply-dealer-xyz">Select</button>
```

But it is not working.

Anybody have some guess?

And another question it is possible do something like this in jquery? (pseudo) :

```
document.querySelectorAll('[classname*=apply-dealer]').innerHTML = "anything"
```

That will change every element containing apply-dealer in class name?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.apply-dealer-xyz')[0].innerHTML = "Deselect";
```

Comment: Thanks. And what about the second question? Is it possible in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `innerHTML` on first element of `querySelectorAll`, because `querySelectorAll` returns array

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.apply-dealer-xyz')[0].innerHTML = "Deselect";
```

```html
<button class="btn cta-primary apply-dealer-xyz">Select</button>
```